# phoneGap/Cordova plugin loading sequence / dealing w/ AdBlock

Tags: javascript, cordova, adblock

I'm using Apache Cordova w/ the AdMob-plugin. If the user uses AdBlock (Browser), the loading sequence fails w/ `GET .../plugins/com.google.cordova.admob/www/AdMob.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` + `Uncaught Error: Module com.google.cordova.admob.AdMob does not exist.` and the rest of the plugins won't be loaded because of that:

```
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady
```

So - how does one deal w/ AdBlock?

The whole loading-thing is triggered by the cordova.js, not my own controllers or app.js.

Answer (score 0):

If run your javascript code with cordova.js in PC/Mac browser, it won't work.

Cordova is a framework to develop hybrid APP, write your own logic with javascript and run in a webview, and cordova.js will handle to call to plugin through the CordovaBridge.

Only when packing your code into a hybrid APP (android or iOS), the call to plugin will work.

So the proper way is, build the app, install into simulator or device, then run the app.

For more details, see the cordova docs here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface